# Как полностью переустановить git с проекта или удалить комиты?

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm

У меня есть проект django в pycharm. Изначально я не шифровал пароли и секретные ключи, из-за чего у меня в комитах они теперь видны. Мне нужно либо полностью переустановить git или как-то удалить все комиты. Просто если я его буду пушить на github, то там можно будет смотреть всю историю. Я искал ответ на вопрос, но в основном я видел только про переустановку git с операционки.

Comment: Удали папку .git в корне проекта.

Comment: Чтобы изменилась история в git репозитории не нужно его переустанавливать (само ПО гита). Вам нужно изменять репозиторий. Как я понял, он у вас ныне локальный, то есть, вы его не пушили в github, значит, можно просто удалить всю локальную историю

Comment: Да, помогло с удалением папки

Comment: Если пароли хранятся в каких-то определенных файлах, можно было [переписать историю](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43762338/9435985)